# How reliable is spectrometry in the determination of the oldest material Startdust?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

After reading one of the latest findings by scientists, Stardust was considered the oldest material on earth. However having not much of an experience with chemistry, I was intrigued upon how scientists were able to find such finding therefore from my understanding, scientists used spectrometry to determine composition of stars to then determine the age of the material(hopefully I am not wrong). However, reading one of the news article, it said that “ stardust that predated the formation of our solar system by billions of years, scientists said on Monday.” This gabbed my attention because it says that scientists found that it was on Monday but the question that came to mind is, how reliable is spectrometry in the determination of such exact findings? Please let me know what you think?

Thanks a lot.

News article: https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2020/1/14/stardust-oldest-material-on-earth-found-inside-meteorite

Comment: It's a matter of radioisotopic dating, with it's own issues. Mass spectroscopy data tell isotopic composition precisely.

Comment: You have to read this original paper in order to get the idea of uncertainties involved in measurements. The estimation was based on Neon isotopes. https://www.pnas.org/content/117/4/1884